# Format Html String in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2

Below is a fragment of my code

```
{% autoescape on %}
                        <li><h4  id="instruction" style = "word-wrap: break-word">{{question_1}}</h4></li>
{% endautoescape %}
```

say {{question_1}} (variable render from server side) is "this is  *an example* ", the output will be like

```
this is *an example*
```

But when i change the content from javascript to something like:

```
document.getElementById("instruction").innerHTML = "this is <i>example 2</i>";
```

the content of the html  changes but it is not italise. hw do i do this. Thanks

Comment: Post javascript code that changes html and maybe someone can figure it out.

Comment: `document.getElementById('instruction').innerHTML = 'this is <i>example 2</i>'`?

Comment: Do you have some CSS that overrides the italic?

Comment: No, no on the page. Just Html

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or something? Because this should just work if you aren't overriding the italic styles.

Comment: Then Html is just as simple as the sample code.. No css

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/YhR2q/), it really would help if you made a fiddle or something.

Comment: i just viewed my page source and found out that <i>ecstatic</i> is seen as &lt;i&gt;ecstatic&lt;/i&gt;

Answer (score 3):

Just found out that the problem is from a tag that was not well decoded. so, i just did this

```
document.getElementById("instruction").innerHTML = "this is <i>example 2</i>".replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>').replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&apos;/g, '\'');
```

and this works well for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem. I noticed you have two ids for just the **h4** tag which is not valid.
The browser will render the first Id and ignore the second. So I advise you first try to know whether your code will work when you use one id tag. Then we can know were the problem is coming from.