# Convert InnerHTML to human readable code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code to take the html code from a `div` and put it into a text box for editing.
If I just take the code and directly print it I get:

```
<h1>hi</h1><p>Sloppy long one line</p><p>and so on</p>
```

This is hard to read so I want it like this:

```
<h1>
hi
</h1>
<p>
Sloppy long one line
</p>
<p>
and so on
</p>
```

I have this:

```
function add_code()
{
    var html= document.getElementById("body_visual_editor").innerHTML //Gets the code
    html= html.replace(/draggable="true"/g, ''); //Removes the draggable attributes that are added to the elements when returning the code to the div 
    html= html.replace(/id="autoid[0-9]+"/g, ''); ////Removes the auto generated ID's that are added to the elements when returning the code to the div
    html= html.replace(/</g, '\n<'); //Adds a line break before tags
    html= html.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n'); //Fixes glitch caused by previous line
    html= html.replace(/>(?!\n)/g, '>\n'); //Adds line break after tag
    document.getElementById("body_code_box").value= html.trim(); //Adds the code to the textarea for editing.
}
```

The issues with it:

when I remove the draggable attributes it leaves 2 spaces at the end of the tag.

when I add the line break before the tags it adds extra line breaks even if there is already one, so I need the `html= html.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n')` to remove it.

That fix leaves an extra line break at the beginning of the code so I need the trim to remove it.

It works but seems very sloppy. Is there a better way to write this to be more streamlined and effective? No JQuery please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Html String in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843378/format-html-string-in-javascript)

Comment: I disagree that the first example is hard to read.

Comment: @canon: Presumably "Sloppy long one line" is a lot, lot longer than in the example..

Comment: @mellamokb I'd argue that adding newlines in this fashion (without tabs or spaces for nesting) is even worse. Might as well just go for a full blown formatting implementation, i.e.: [prettify](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgoogle-code-prettify%2F&ei=QMRIVZDzCIHZggSnhIGgCA&usg=AFQjCNHBCSZN0pbSoic2KQtu-h73hXTD2A&bvm=bv.92291466,d.eXY).

Comment: @connon: it would be nice to indent the code and formate it properly. But as this is all done with JavaScript alone the more formatting i do the more complex the code becomes, so right now the line breaks at least make it readable enough to make sense of and edit.

Comment: @Zaper127, I think I have a solution, but it's in my head, and I've been busy. I plan to drop an answer here in a couple days though. Are you opposed to a solution that walks the DOM tree recursively to make the necessary changes instead of using regex? It will be easy-to-read, easy-to-modify, and should run very fast (but I haven't written the code, so you know, we'll see)

Comment: @jakar, that could work

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I understand what you want.

```
var text = document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML;
var find = '<';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
text = text.replace(re, '\n<');
find = '>';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
text = text.replace(re, '>\n');
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rbmtky8r/7/)

Comment: This does not show the html tags as was asked by @Zaper127

Comment: I don't get what he wants. The text with, or without the tags ?

With the tags : use `innerHTML`. Without : `innerText`.

Comment: Hmm I'm sorry, but as a non-native english speaker, I have some problems with terms like these ones, so I don't know what they mean, and due to the way he uses them, I don't think I will find an easy way to translate them.

Comment: My main concern is finding a solution were I don't have to remove consecutive line breaks just to clean up the code. Is there a regex i can use like the one i ised for the >? Also the extra spaces left from removing the atributes leave the code looking a little messy.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that this was never answered properly. All that needs to be done is to replace the HTML Characters with their relative Entity name.

Like so (Run the snippet to see it in action):

```js
let text = document.getElementById('raw').innerHTML,
find = '<',
re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
text = text.replace(re, '&lt;');

find = '>';
re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
text = text.replace(re, '&gt;');

document.getElementById('CodeOut').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<section id="raw">
<h1>hi</h1><p>Sloppy long one line</p><p>and so on</p>
</section>
<section id="Code" style="background-color:grey;color:#fff;padding:10px;">
<pre><code id="CodeOut"></code></pre>
</section>
```